# How to remove empty spaces in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a text:

```
text = '''
    Wales greatest moment. Lille is so close to the Belgian 
    border, 
    this was essentially a home game for one of the tournament favourites. Their 
    confident supporters mingled with their new Welsh fans on the streets, 
    buying into the carnival spirit - perhaps more relaxed than some might have 
    been before a quarter-final because they thought this was their time.
    In the driving rain, Wales produced the best performance in their history to 
    carry the nation into uncharted territory. Nobody could quite believe it.'''
```

I have a code:

```
 words = text.replace('.',' ').replace(',',' ').replace('\n',' ').split(' ')
    print(words)
```

And Output:

```
['Wales', 'greatest', 'moment', '', 'Lille', 'is', 'so', 'close', 'to', 'the', 'Belgian', 'border', '', '', 'this', 'was', 'essentially', 'a', 'home', 'game', 'for', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'tournament', 'favourites', '', 'Their', '', 'confident', 'supporters', 'mingled', 'with', 'their', 'new', 'Welsh', 'fans', 'on', 'the', 'streets', '', '', 'buying', 'into', 'the', 'carnival', 'spirit', '-', 'perhaps', 'more', 'relaxed', 'than', 'some', 'might', 'have', '', 'been', 'before', 'a', 'quarter-final', 'because', 'they', 'thought', 'this', 'was', 'their', 'time', '', 'In', 'the', 'driving', 'rain', '', 'Wales', 'produced', 'the', 'best', 'performance', 'in', 'their', 'history', 'to', '', 'carry', 'the', 'nation', 'into', 'uncharted', 'territory', '', 'Nobody', 'could', 'quite', 'believe', 'it', '']
```

You can see, list have empty spaces, I remove `'\n'`, `','` and `'.'`.

But now I have not idea how to remove this spaces.

Comment: If you don't pass an argument to `split()`, it uses *arbitrary* whitespace sequences as the delimiter, rather than each individual `' '` character.

Comment: A simple comprehension can take care of that easily: `words = [_ for _ in text.replace('.',' ').replace(',',' ').split() if _.strip()]`.

Comment: @accdias What means `[_ for _ in text.replace('.',' ').replace(',',' ').split() if _.strip()]` ?

Comment: Means "add `_` to `words` if  `_` is not empty".

Comment: Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) them, if you don't like them

```
no_empties = list(filter(None, words))
```

> If function is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

This works because empty elements are considered falsey.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

The original answer does not product the same output as mentioned in the comments, because of the dash symbol, to avoid that:

```
import re
words = re.findall(r'[\w-]+', text)
```

**Original Answer**

You can directly get what you want with the `re` module

```
import re
words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)


['Wales',
 'greatest',
 'moment',
 'Lille',
 'is',
 'so',
 'close',
 'to',
 'the',
 'Belgian',
 'border',
 'this',
 'was',
 'essentially',
 'a',
 'home',
 'game',
 'for',
 'one',
 'of',
 'the',
 'tournament',
 'favourites',
 'Their',
 'confident',
 'supporters',
 'mingled',
 'with',
 'their',
 'new',
 'Welsh',
 'fans',
 'on',
 'the',
 'streets',
 'buying',
 'into',
 'the',
 'carnival',
 'spirit',
 'perhaps',
 'more',
 'relaxed',
 'than',
 'some',
 'might',
 'have',
 'been',
 'before',
 'a',
 'quarter',
 'final',
 'because',
 'they',
 'thought',
 'this',
 'was',
 'their',
 'time',
 'In',
 'the',
 'driving',
 'rain',
 'Wales',
 'produced',
 'the',
 'best',
 'performance',
 'in',
 'their',
 'history',
 'to',
 'carry',
 'the',
 'nation',
 'into',
 'uncharted',
 'territory',
 'Nobody',
 'could',
 'quite',
 'believe',
 'it']
```

Comment: This does not produce the identical output.

Comment: You are close but the `-` is throwing this off

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this issue is that your text value is indented in every line with 4 single spaces, not because your code is flawed. You could add `.replace('  ','')` to your 'words' logic to fix this if you mean to have 4 single spaces every line, or you could refer to Thomas Weller's solution, which will solve the problem no matter how many consecutive single spaces you leave

Comment: @Mr.Robot Make sure the first parameter of .replace has exactly four spaces